# Is it safe to modify the android_native_app_glue.c file in the Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk

I was thinking about modifying the onCreate() method in this file. Is this, and other modifications of the android_native_app_glue.c file safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change this file, as you can modify any file under **sources** - they are all compiled into your app, except that for STL you may need to additionally require rebuild of the STL library.